# Problem in installing Ubuntu 15.10 in windows 10

Tags: boot

I was running windows 10 on my HP Laptop, and decided to install Ubuntu 15.10. To do this, I took the following steps:

1. Erased all the data in a partition of my Laptop.
2. Created the Ubuntu bootable USB using PowerISO in windows.
3. Restarted the computer and pressed the F9 to enter my laptop's boot order menu.
4. I selected the USB in boot options.
5. Selected the "Something Else" option.
6. I chose the erased partition: 
   a. Chose the ext4 filesystem, Logical, from the beginning
   b. Mount point `/`
7. Then, I installed Ubuntu in the selected partition, in which there is no Windows 10 boot loader.

The problem is, when I boot the computer, I do not get any OS showing up. Could someone please assist me in attempting to solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems won't boot if you install them to logical partitions. Data partitions can be logical, but OSes need to be on primary if you want them to boot.

Reinstall Ubuntu and format the partition as primary this time. Once the installation finishes, you should have no trouble booting.